# Reading Serial port data continuously in powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, serial-port

I am trying to write a powershell script that sends a command to a serial device and then keeps reading data coming from the device.

```
[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::GetPortNames()
Write-Host "Select Serial Port"
$portName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Serial Device Name'
Write-Host "Using $portName..."

$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort $portName, 115200, None, 8, one
$port.ReadTimeout = 1000
$port.Open()

$port.WriteLine("start\n\r")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
while ($x = $port.ReadExisting())
{
    Write-Host $x
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 300
}
$port.Close()
```

The above script exits as soon as it receives 1st line from the device. I tried changing the sleep time in the while loop, but the behaviour is the same.

Comment: I just tried this the other day and had some weird issues as well.  Are you sure the ``while ($x = $port.ReadExisting())`` is behaving as you're expecting?

Comment: No, I believe that it takes a lot  of time to read the bytes in the buffer. I am sure that the device I am talking to responds immediately.

Comment: I would suggest ``while ($port.IsOpen)`` from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48661245/3718361

Comment: `while ($port.IsOpen)` did not work, but checking it in an if statement and running the script in an infinite loop worked.

Comment: You can subscribe to the DataRecieved event which is exposed by the SerialPort class to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here...
The following code worked for me to read continuously from the serial port

```
Write-Host "Select Serial Port"
$portName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Serial Device Name'
Write-Host "Using $portName..."

$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort $portName, 115200, None, 8, one
$port.Open()

Write-Output $port

for(;;)
{
    if ($port.IsOpen)
    {
        $data = $port.ReadLine()
        Write-Output $data
    }
}
```